# I have an arraylist of multiple lists( strings).I want to display that arraylist in tableview using javafx

Tags: java, javafx-8

```
List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
TableView<List<String>> table = new TableView<List<String>>();
```

Each row in `tableview` corresponds to a list in `arraylist`. If I make any changes in `tableview` in one or multiple lists,those changes should be automatically applied to the lists in `arraylist`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i am new to java ..I want to display all the lists of arraylist in a tableview in javafx and  Each row in tableview corresponds to a list in arraylist. If I make any changes in tableview in one or multiple lists,those changes should be automatically applied to the lists in arraylist.